# NullPointer Exception while writing to file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, iterator, bufferedwriter

So, I've been trying to write a method where I can write fields of Item, Client and Order objects, but as I run this program it gives nullpointexception error and I have no idea what causes it. As an argument, I give path of a file, for example : "C:\Java\info.txt"

Any help regarding this issue would be grateful.

```
public class IO {
    ItemClass item;
    ClientClass client;
    OrderClass order;
    private static HashSet<ItemClass> Items;
    private static HashSet<ClientClass> Orders;
    private static HashSet<OrderClass> Clients;



public void writeToFile(String directory) throws IOException{
    File file = new File(directory);

    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile(); 
    }

    BufferedWriter bufferedW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(directory));
    Orders=getOrders();
    Iterator <OrderClass>iteratorOrders = Orders.iterator();
    while(iteratorOrders.hasNext()){
        order = iteratorOrders.next();
        bufferedW.write(order.getIdNumber());
        bufferedW.write(order.getPersonalID());
        bufferedW.write(order.getAddress());
        bufferedW.write(order.getCountry());
        bufferedW.write(order.getStatus());
    }
    Clients=getClients();
    Iterator <ClientClass>iteratorClients = Clients.iterator();
    while(iteratorClients.hasNext()){
        client = iteratorClients.next();
        bufferedW.write(client.getPersonalID());
        bufferedW.write(client.getName());
        bufferedW.write(client.getSurname());
        bufferedW.write(client.getBirthDate());
        boolean active = client.getIsActive();
        boolean activeOrder = client.getHasActiveOrder();
        bufferedW.write(String.valueOf(active));
        bufferedW.write(String.valueOf(activeOrder));
    }
    Items=getItems();
    Iterator <ItemClass>iteratorItems = Items.iterator();
    while(iteratorItems.hasNext()){
        item = iteratorItems.next();
        bufferedW.write(item.getItemID());
        int amount = item.getAmount();
        double price = item.getPrice();
        bufferedW.write(String.valueOf(amount));
        bufferedW.write(String.valueOf(price));
        bufferedW.write(item.getName());
        bufferedW.write(item.getType());
        bufferedW.write(item.getMadeIn());
    }
    bufferedW.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please add the details of your NullPointerException?

Comment: @razong
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
 at eshop.IO.IO.writeToFile(IO.java:73)
 at eshop.IO.UI.output(UI.java:495)
 at eshop.IO.UI.executeIO(UI.java:300)
 at eshop.IO.UI.inputOutput(UI.java:405)
 at eshop.IO.UI.executeFirst(UI.java:76)
 at eshop.IO.UI.menu(UI.java:41)
 at eshop.EShop.main(EShop.java:25)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @razong
I've used more classes, but I believe error comes from this class. Also, I've used this class to read from file, but as it works, I cut that part out. Line 73 is bufferedW.write(order.getStatus());

Comment: Did you escape the \ in the filename`

Comment: @tobias_k 
No, I wrote C:\\Java\\info.txt, mb it got edited or something like that

Comment: If you wrote it like that, that should be okay. Try debugging. Maybe some of the orders, clients or items are `null`.

Comment: Well, thanks to you @tobias_k, it worked, if you need like "best answer", write me a solution and i'll give you that for the great help.